# How to add a click listener to amCharts bullets in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I implemented custom bullets with [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) and would now like to add a click listener for each bullet with which I can open a popup with detailed information on the respective bullet.

We are currently using [amcharts/amcharts3-angular](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2) and have set up our configuration accordingly.

My function within my chart service, with which the chart is generated, looks like this *(I simplified it for stackoverflow)*:

```
  getChart(series, chart, amChart, includeInfos) {
    let colorIndex = 0;

    if (series && series.identifiers.length > 0 && series.values.length > 0) {
      const graphs = [];
      let legend = {};
      chart.anomalies = 0;
      chart.insights = 0;


      series.identifiers.forEach(identifier => {
        if (identifier.includes('_info1')) {
          this.transformInfos1ToBubbles(series, identifier, chart);
          return;
        }
        if (identifier.includes('_info2')) {
          this.transformInfos2ToBubbles(series, identifier, chart);
          return;
        }
        graphs.push({visibleInLegend: false, lineAlpha: 0, valueField: identifier, customBulletField: identifier + '_info1'});

        graphs.push({visibleInLegend: false, lineAlpha: 0, valueField: identifier, customBulletField: identifier + '_info2'});

        graphs.push({
          // some other configuration
          // ...
          // ...
          bullet: 'custom',
          bulletBorderAlpha: 0,
          bulletSize: 10,
          customBullet: '/assets/images/transparent.png',
          hideBulletsCount: 0,
          // some other configuration
          // ...
          // ...
        });
      ...
```

The "tranformInfos2ToBullets" method looks like this:

```
  private transformInfos2ToBubbles(data, identifier, chart) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data.values.length; j++) {
      if (data.values[j][identifier]) {
        if (chart) {
          chart.infos2++;
        }
        data.values[j][identifier] = './info1.png';
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to retrieve the DOM elements of those bullets to register a click events on them ?

Comment: @LoganWlv Unfortunately, that doesn't work in my case, because the bullets contain information in the TypeScript code that has to be passed on. In addition, nothing useful is generated in the DOM -----> <g transform = "translate (56,100)" aria-label = "901011.AI.10 Oct 16, 2020 262.77"> <image x = "0" y = "0 "width =" 10 "height =" 10 "xlink: href =" / assets / images / transparent.png "transform =" translate (-5, -5) "> </image> </g>